# Can't correctly type JSON logic with a dynamic operator

Tags: typescript, jsonlogic

I'm using the definitely typed package for [json-logic-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-logic-js).

I can't seem to get TypeScript to compile when I'm using a dynamic operator, but it works fine if I use a static one. This works:

```
const staticRule: RulesLogic = {
  '==': [{var:'one'},1]
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
const op: ReservedOperations[] = ['==','>=','<=','===']

const dynamicOperator = op[1]

const dynamicRule: RulesLogic = {
  [dynamicOperator]: [{var:'one'},1]
}
```

I get the error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: (number | { var: string; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'RulesLogic<never>'.
  Property 'log' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: (number | { var: string; })[]; }' but required in type 'JsonLogicLog<never>'.
```

Here's a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2qAuqD26BnUZXAJ1ACsD8BaAG1wHNUBjGq0AJgDoAGAKBCgACqVwVYLLAC5QACyxZoBaSGZY5AVwBG3FrgC2wCgHcAhgjlmDBY9XT0mrdgQDEpWBYOxBYACIoGNh4hKDakLLgHgBuZuigADwKSipq2Fq6+kZRsLHoAHy+oMUlpWXFAFJmANbwAEK4+PBJisqqwOoZeobGNbDajeiwvJyFQgFomDj4KvKtqR3pOt1GE0FYsHSQUHAIwGtTm9swsAhFALJBBpoGECcAyiykqNBYoABqsKQEIbIALNwAKz8EH8LAnUAAJVg6GssHAuAAkugEuB8qAALygADe-FKAG0ANKgDCgWqQXDICCgMxEYmwAAeG3QCCIAAMMAASbEAVWgcFILFpsASBCwz3QjHyAF9uQAZXAmL5CggisUSqXStmgAD8oA56G1skJAF1IkSTQBufjS62CABU9rx9ogclQRHdNNAmhwdGwkFA4Lg3tVCDCm0VxDIgbk8AARKhkHHQLgBWZpuhuM7QAB5Z7MWF0WTJNogMVmFjVXDRL7IBgmFbAMzAABsAA4AMwAdm7Xb+wC7LcBAE4213ncAwRDzgBBAAaiPOPPOAH0Z3K5TmAOoAUT8K7qOZ5ADk-DPIQBNTGgNu8a1B+DnMz804JPElcCaaB0eCM5ms710GqdBFXQfETQAGnfYpoQITQ6DeP8YQAzQgJAkwwJNa9wKg0oAGFcFQxCmWQohoQsfAthnUhSDMSAEnQG5tC+dEsRw-hWNAAiiPxAByH9JQ0XisKQlkiFnBcl1XddN13fdDxPM9L2g3UoVgOCEJUyIvx-UBRIA8CVL1QzSlkWD4OI-8iBMko9SfF8EFRHTYAgiBnNc-FuC87j0CwVyAEYTUKUzQHs3YnO-Fy1I0t4AB9QE8rzzIQ1yvO4T9IsghK0p8vzQEC-JrWAR1sx5UMo3IDR40TZNUy+dMQlckw3RYORAz6Ig4hpGi6JTKlcAQMMBMYDRsziMMzFAAwrhuPqYw8eAAAoOwASj0n9vF8ggs1Ae1JwfUAZ3QSBqNoyAc2QHNBrlGERrkS50A7bC4kgVKvLC198Re1yXqCq0QQO2CvhrBAczTDMiAxFT4t42JSF46HQF46aCB+SUEdKGGUbRxgV2obwMZKGHE0J4oYYxDFSdAcmKapmGAEJKcR3jGaZzGkfpumOc55myC53jxv5-IhbZomkYSfmElFsmkYMMwGX56b0H5gBqfmaH5+1+eAfmAFJFeffm0AQr5+Y8BBNBYWB+bMOg6H5kChn5-HreZ7xSEYV32d4jB+aFLBnZ0dV+YYRheLtYqnV211PSFeJmJpeJcG0CQpFAEx0kTgNyT0hkrdeGN4A8VVSBBslYEgbbs3AHM-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-JuScsFbjDEgpyeC2FzyHmfP+d8wF7yYXItBT435mK4XQohV8sFSLPGEuxQSlFULplywZAcuiRySUUqceckoStaX0XJVinZ8y1ZsvpVkxlOy8kcrhfMjWvLhXPMiRK758ytbioRd8qVCqwXzJ1vK3FkqhXKqcfM-WwKNXfOJfyzlliqXPn1Qyk18KDWUpUsbZhFrjVwqNbc1F0zzaWySRiy1zqcU+sRX6p1ALpm2yLAlU6dLpVgutf61FeTvVBsNYG11trSiOy9RG9l2qdkushU4-F2b7nJrzREvpLtmmZr5SmplubSWlvjVGslhaXlUq+J7XllbG2Cvil2s50yMCZsddW9Jh11m9qIX0jA9xxRBI+bGolxa62mpUv7dV86mXTLgtodUQ6S1FvHQWm1Taj0joPdM0OwT10ROtNKAGEIKj2FCe8eBOTxGkUkQgcBhYeEwKxAowhsDWDVDfKUDhdAuFYNkXw3ytY2HOpUrDeBCNdkHQffgUJlxUbUNffpIgIiv0yOgXIv9uRFFYmEEBkDJQwMQdEUR6DAi4OIoQ4E9GHF7z3sffYzDON7iJJwyRMSH6CN0B-cR0A-7OIUcrFR4oNH1LA0g-Rwg-DYNCOYxc1juMXbIY48GND6BQmIipORyj8mS7cKgypmDLC2GuR9sgS5en4AGdCTuAAjpoW2gGZPmcU3RnBIQCCqds1beztMUOcfQ-Y6dzwpAea83QHzwG-OYIC7w6zjGwtIwppTSL+muOaOPLgLACXvOmd85whTaWxMMbU1FFmeXnOgFczFmdUhiulc8+VkQZmqsWaU4FuroWGtjPyy5wrrBjywEYBl5Lwj+v+dq5l+r9nObjZa5NlgfhCJP1gNN2bv7euVfA9Vyzyngs2cEaN9bzXWuaLzAJiR+HpGias-I0jAGKvAZUql87Q2Vsjfgxcvm7HgETei5oo6jk7lvqEy9kIhGAcfYIVJyjv3Fs1as5drLIoNMNMFmD1DW2ADiHh0xfHAFYFEsPcPCde8tlHZHjs-dA5j-7GWcf1eBw04WROouGfsWTzwzCqdxDzGVugT330I4gW95TTOvss9k4ddng3Ocheuzzjp+QmYbfu6wG6qMxc09OXDgCsvv3vZI6j+bGPTsDfSxDTXTHDUIYlvzgrkPDfqQICbiX3Wpe08ExbqRiP5fI5t8z6TrPqNq6d0Fl36m3cXKlrp8Hm3vcsCfAyaX8Ow9y8Z1HpXMeVd-fV87q7ruiUsflun4nWeHp59D5+hn1uJOfbRzJ+3tHltc6B-jjpSt68C9CfcG4ze8MF6twr4vXfY9yfj33pPeOU8NLVp7iHgvNF+ETMgL4MJk8WPN1P1v4ei8d9t99svS-scr+10jDWm-M-b9YKIAalssCT-p+f9vkm7ds4O5LZ35V5H4+IIZazP4G4sAACKmgJWqAMIX+wez20+SOc2c+ABceQBWOF29+g+SMOsUBW20IcszcXw3+lu6BR2-+1+PeZ2FeieoBq+NeFy+sxBjez4lBaBEeGBl+0e6OgBveIBuOD+yMhsHBr+LATcJspA3BZ+hef+neWBi+OBHOleohBBvE9qpskhoS0IFsYBYidOVBvBNByhdBQhDBCew2WuWhHqVsI+XuUhYG8hImF+tByu9Bjuy+zBYhoaThW+oSxWQwbhbes+-BJegh2BwheBfhWh6agRL+Y+-GKBMuPBHhFhXhVhPhIh3OWhOmeh3GbaLBuiJ+P+ihERnhpe3hwBcRmha+Q+JRSR0ByIlaaR+eChM+kekRnE0IsI3gCIyIKupe5eNhgOdhSaPs6AmalyRRmiyIsW2GHRLe7hShV+akAx8ISIKIKkoxt+9R+RUxU6M66MhQ+uW2eE6YYRv+VRWRNRORdRAO-ekxrBDS-sLRW24+264oNxlRPR1R0RqhsRzx+BjRSMW6wc8xhuTAfx3RfBgJ3ejxuBoJ8R4J-ETA6eGeva5RphmRV+iMAwuAP4cQiMVCkoiMjEBgzEpAIIpQQgM4LAVsWGkooAfg6Yk0NAcwKQ7QN838Z8dUzx3ACgBgdArgFYzJOMNACAHJiM0Bz6chzycpW2PGyx3yypjecS1CfG3gcKdJJQQgoSicYYDQxJng8QfeoAXJR8vJ9g-JPQgpnOwpWAoprgd8NA40NARJJJDgjpEMGpUhxmAZbmgewZbWcWXWiWYZRWJWku0ZrASxHWsZoZ7M0BB2GW8Z22u2P46ZGYmZj2SpqZW20OepKkQgx4NwXwrAuY2OVp3JpYdglE9ijYfpQWzprpVJVZbArZMwmZwuFOpAJuepRZWe-Zou1OAeiWw5Ys0BRufu1O05Mss5vu-upAkui5eS0BOeG58UW5GAO5yRMWE+hZM5W2u+yA++Hg6ARheimZ7+hhyB6pI5UhcBCBSBB50BpBZg5Bip6pZZYAmaNZF2dZNpIAfJzZAp2O7ZYp8CZ0NAPZhAmZ9kH5W2MhzCKFWeBhnqGFLhdsOFwRTQ+FMWqRT5p5jeJRRFCxMx6ySp-5O8pxjAQFzxIF8wtpTZmiLZUFIpYp5JjA8F2OmZixDFlFrAVxj5YK+pxQQgmGVsdscQsAhERA1prFYFdpEFDpXFLpYpKMsldA8lilmZGipZ9JAFYCrJlpi0oFjZ6A9pRgFgCAK4CF0FK0iMdylopQoI+ghAbwqYZk1hfe4E2EnSvEEEbyIVvEaeoVuWwkIIXlYoiAkAAxrAP60YWIqY+IgUsVMwbwCAiV1grAHil6xq14uIxQ+IuVSVLAKVpAtC+I2IKivETQvE0oEEmVt6-AcVbw5YOALAhVi61ZWIpVOW6K9V8C0gjVTsLVbVQAA).

---

Even if I specify just both those operators it still doesn't work:

```
const createRulesLogic = (operation: '==' | '!='): RulesLogic => ({
  [operation]: [{var:'one'},1]
})
```

Results in the error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: (number | { var: string; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'RulesLogic<never>'.
  Property 'log' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: (number | { var: string; })[]; }' but required in type 'JsonLogicLog<never>'.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2qAuqD26BnUZXAJ1ACsD8BaAG1wHNUBjGq0AJgDoAGAKBCgACqVwVYLLAC5QACyxZoBaSGZY5AVwBG3FrgC2wCgHcAhgjlmDBY9XT0mrdgQDEpWBYOxBYACIoGNh4hKDakLLgHgBuZuigADwKSipq2Fq6+kZRsLHoAHy+oMUlpWXFAFJmANbwAEK4+PBJisqqwOoZeobGNbDajeiwvJyFQgFomDj4KvKtqR3pOt1GE0FYsHSQUHAIwGtTm9swsAhFALJBBpoGECcAyiykqNBYoABqsKQEIbIALNwAKz8EH8LAnUAAJVg6GssHAuAAkugEuB8qAALygADe-FKAG0ANKgDCgWqQXDICCgMxEYmwAAeG3QCCIAAMMAASbEAVWgcFILFpsASBCwz3QjHyAF9uQAZXAmL5CggisUSqXStmgAD8oA56G1skJAF1IkSTQBufjS62CABU9rx9ogclQRHdNNAmhwdGwkFA4Lg3tVCDCm0VxDIgbk8AARKhkHHQLgBWZpuhuM7QAB5Z7MWF0WTJNogMVmFjVXDRL7IBgmFbAMzAABsAA4AMwAdm7Xb+wC7LcBAE4213ncAwRDzgBBAAaiPOPPOAH0Z3K5TmAOoAUT8K7qOZ5ADk-DPIQBNTGgNu8a1B+DnMz804JPElcCaaB0eCM5ms710GqdBFXQfETQAGnfYpoQITQ6DeP8YQAzQgJAkwwJNa9wKg0oAGFcFQxCmWQohoQsfAthnUhSDMSAEnQG5tC+dEsRw-hWNAAiiPxAByH9JQ0XisKQlkiFnBcl1XddN13fdDxPM9L2g3UoVgOCEJUyIvx-UBRIA8CVL1QzSlkWD4OI-8iBMko9SfF8EFRHTYAgiBnNc-FuC87j0CwVyAEYTUKUzQHs3YnO-Fy1I0t4AB9QE8rzzIQ1yvO4T9IsghK0p8vzQEC-JrWAR1sx5UMo3IDR40TZNUy+dMQlckw3RYORAz6Ig4hpGi6JTKlcAQMMBMYDRsziMMzFAAwrhuPqYw8eAAAoOwASj0n9vF8ggs1Ae1JwfUAZ3QSBqNoyAc2QHNBrlGERrkS50A7bC4kgVKvLC198Re1yXqCq0QQO2CvhrBAczTDMiAxFT4t42JSF46HQF46aCB+SUEdKGGUbRxgV2obwMZKGHE0J4oYYxDFSdAcmKapmGAEJKcR3jGaZzGkfpumOc55myC53jxv5-IhbZomkYSfmElFsmkYMMwGX56b0H5gBqfmaH5+1+eAfmAFJFeffm0AQr5+Y8BBNBYWB+bMOg6H5kChn5-HreZ7xSEYV32d4jB+aFLBnZ0dV+YYRheLtYqnV211PSFeJmJpeJcG0CQpFAEx0kTgNyT0hkrdeGN4A8VVSBBslYEgbbs3AHM-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-JuScsFbjDEgpyeC2FzyHmfP+d8wF7yYXItBT435mK4XQohV8sFSLPGEuxQSlFULplywZAcuiRySUUqceckoStaX0XJVinZ8y1ZsvpVkxlOy8kcrhfMjWvLhXPMiRK758ytbioRd8qVCqwXzJ1vK3FkqhXKqcfM-WwKNXfOJfyzlliqXPn1Qyk18KDWUpUsbZhFrjVwqNbc1F0zzaWySRiy1zqcU+sRX6p1ALpm2yLAlU6dLpVgutf61FeTvVBsNYG11trSiOy9RG9l2qdkushU4-F2b7nJrzREvpLtmmZr5SmplubSWlvjVGslhaXlUq+J7XllbG2Cvil2s50yMCZsddW9Jh11m9qIX0jA9xxRBI+bGolxa62mpUv7dV86mXTLgtodUQ6S1FvHQWm1Taj0joPdM0OwT10ROtNKAGEIKj2FCe8eBOTxGkUkQgcBhYeEwKxAowhsDWDVDfKUDhdAuFYNkXw3ytY2HOpUrDeBCNdkHQffgUJlxUbUNffpIgIiv0yOgXIv9uRFFYmEEBkDJQwMQdEUR6DAi4OIoQ4E9GHF7z3sffYzDON7iJJwyRMSH6CN0B-cR0A-7OIUcrFR4oNH1LA0g-Rwg-DYNCOYxc1juMXbIY48GND6BQmIipORyj8mS7cKgypmDLC2GuR9sgS5en4AGdCTuAAjpoW2gGZPmcU3RnBIQCCqds1beztMUOcfQ-Y6dzwpAea83QHzwG-OYIC7w6zjGwtIwppTSL+muOaOPLgLACXvOmd85whTaWxMMbU1FFmeXnOgFczFmdUhiulc8+VkQZmqsWaU4FuroWGtjPyy5wrrBjywEYBl5Lwj+v+dq5l+r9nObjZa5NlgfhCJP1gNN2bv7euVfA9Vyzyngs2cEaN9bzXWuaLzAJiR+HpGias-I0jAGKvAZUql87Q2Vsjfgxcvm7HgETei5oo6jk7lvqEy9kIhGAcfYIVJyjv3Fs1as5drLIoNMNMFmD1DW2ADiHh0xfHAFYFEsPcPCde8tlHZHjs-dA5j-7GWcf1eBw04WROouGfsWTzwzCqdxDzGVugT330I4gW95TTOvss9k4ddng3Ocheuzzjp+QmYbfu6wG6qMxc09OXDgCsvv3vZI6j+bGPTsDfSxDTXTHDUIYlvzgrkPDfqQICbiX3Wpe08ExbqRiP5fI5t8z6TrPqNq6d0Fl36m3cXKlrp8Hm3vcsCfAyaX8Ow9y8Z1HpXMeVd-fV87q7ruiUsflun4nWeHp59D5+hn1uJOfbRzJ+3tHltc6B-jjpSt68C9CfcG4ze8MF6twr4vXfY9yfj33pPeOU8NLVp7iHgvNF+ETMgL4MJk8WPN1P1v4ei8d9t99svS-scr+10jDWm-M-b9YKIAalssCT-p+f9vkm7ds4O5LZ35V5H4+IIZazP4G4sAACKmgJWqAMIX+wez20+SOc2c+ABceQBWOF29+g+SMOsUBW20IcszcXw3+lu6BR2-+1+PeZ2FeieoBq+NeFy+sxBjez4lBaBEeGBl+0e6OgBveIBuOD+yMhsHBr+LATcJspA3BZ+hef+neWBi+OBHOleohBBvE9qpskhoS0IFsYBYidOVBvBNByhdBQhDBCew2WuWhHqVsI+XuUhYG8hImF+tByu9Bjuy+zBYhoaThW+oSxWQwbhbes+-BJegh2BwheBfhWh6agRL+Y+-GKBMuPBHhFhXhVhPhIh3OWhOmeh3GbaLBuiJ+P+ihERnhpe3hwBcRmha+Q+JRSR0ByIlaaR+eChM+kekRnE0IsI3gCIyIKupe5eNhgOdhSaPs6AmalyRRmiyIsW2GHRLe7hShV+akAx8ISIKIKkoxt+9R+RUxU6M66MhQ+uW2eE6YYRv+VRWRNRORdRAO-ekxrBDS-sLRW24+264oNxlRPR1R0RqhsRzx+BjRSMW6wc8xhuTAfx3RfBgJ3ejxuBoJ8R4J-ETA6eGeva5RphmRV+iMAwuAP4cQiMVCkoiMjEBgzEpAIIpQQgM4LAVsWGkooAfg6Yk0NAcwKQ7QN838Z8dUzx3ACgBgdArgFYzJOMNACAHJiM0Bz6chzycpW2PGyx3yypjecS1CfG3gcKdJJQQgoSicYYDQxJng8QfeoAXJR8vJ9g-JPQgpnOwpWAoprgd8NA40NARJJJDgjpEMGpUhxmAZbmgewZbWcWXWiWYZRWJWku0ZrASxHWsZoZ7M0BB2GW8Z22u2P46ZGYmZj2SpqZW20OepKkQgx4NwXwrAuY2OVp3JpYdglE9ijYfpQWzprpVJVZbArZMwmZwuFOpAJuepRZWe-Zou1OAeiWw5Ys0BRufu1O05Mss5vu-upAkui5eS0BOeG58UW5GAO5yRMWE+hZM5W2u+yA++Hg6ARheimZ7+hhyB6pI5UhcBCBSBB50BpBZg5Bip6pZZYAmaNZF2dZNpIAfJzZAp2O7ZYp8CZ0NAPZhAmZ9kH5W2MhzCKFWeBhnqGFLhdsOFwRTQ+FMWqRT5p5jeJRRFCxMx6ySp-5O8pxjAQFzxIF8wtpTZmiLZUFIpYp5JjA8F2OmZixDFlFrAVxj5YK+pxQQgmGVsdscQsAhERA1prFYFdpEFDpXFLpYpKMsldA8lilmZGipZ9JAFYCrJlpi0oFjZ6A9pRgFgCAK4CF0FK0iMdylopQoI+ghAbwTwIusARpWIi0CFsgnSvEeSjWvEK0l6xqmI6Ii0uIBICFZo+I2IKivETQvE0oEEgUNoLlIIXlYooA5YOALAHi0VAVSiHSXSKVaVGVWVOV0oQAA)

Comment: It seems the width of `ReservedOperations` is the problem - `const op = ['==','>=','<=','==='] as const satisfies readonly ReservedOperations[];` works fine, because those four strings can be keys for that value, but other valid `ReservedOperations` cannot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the comment. I'm not quite sute I follow. What do you mean `those four strings can be keys for that value` - the value being the array `[ {var: 'one' }, 1]`?

Comment: Yes; that's a valid value in a RulesLogic for those four keys, and maybe other ReservedOperations, but not for _all_ ReservedOperations. Precisely which error you get out of TS for such complex types tends to just be which one it gave up on last.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - ah that makes (somewhat) sense. So I guess the solution here would be that I need to be more precise about which dynamic operator I could be using

Comment: Actually @jonrsharpe, I've edited my post (after somebody has downvoted it for some reason), even if I specify just both those operators it still doesn't work.

Comment: What I suggested above works because it creates a "const context" in which the string literal types don't get widened to string: https://tsplay.dev/w2kAjN. As you can see from `{ [x: string]: ... }`, too wide, and again `[ {var: 'one' }, 1]` isn't valid for all possible keys.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you help me understand how they get widened to string when I specify the type as something more specific as the argument to the function?

Answer (score 0):

`staticRule` is automatically recognized as a valid `RulesLogic`, in particular as `JsonLogicEqual` due to the fact that you explicit set the operator/ket to `==`.

The "dynamic" one doesn't know in advance which operator will you use and warns you that, if the dynamic operator would be a `log`, your rule will be missing the `log` key inside the object.

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how would I go about constructing a RulesLogic using a dynamic operator?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've reached the edge of what TS can reason about at compile-time:

```js
const enabledOps = [
    '==', '!='
] as const satisfies readonly ReservedOperation[]

const createLogic1 = (operation: typeof enabledOps[1]): RulesLogic => ({
    [operation]: [{var: 'one'}, 1]
})
// ^ type-checks

const createLogic0or1 = (operation: typeof enabledOps[0 | 1]): RulesLogic => ({
    [operation]: [{var: 'one'}, 1]
})
// ^ this errors, but absolutely shouldn't
```

Congratulations!